# Making Iframe default picture same size as blank iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, image

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I have my iframe set to relative. My question is how do I set the default image to resize to the size of the iframe automatically ? The code...

```
<iframe name="iframe1"src="../Pictures/coolcenturylink.jpg" height="%"width="%"/></iframe>


iframe
{
position:relative;
float:right;
height:80%;
width:84.5%;
top:%;
background-color:;
}
```

Edit point below...

```
<img src="coolcenturylink.jpg"/>

.coolcenturylink.jpg
{
    max-width: 100%;
}

<iframe name="iframe1"src="../Pictures/coolcenturylink.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: http://codecopy.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/ghost-iframe-crossdomain-iframe-resize/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Iframes contain separate content from your site. You can't pass css into iframes** so there's no way to target the image you are loading from this end.

You can style the image in the page on the page it's loading from. If you create a second html page with just the image and apply the css to it there it will load with it.

**Working example**
http://jsfiddle.net/KArXd/

**Image page being loaded in the iframe:**
http://jsfiddle.net/NsJyR/

You still run into a problem with the height.

I'm not sure why you're loading an image with an iframe, but if you change it to an img tag you can apply a max-width.

```
.your-image {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: My thinking is just to have something in place when they don't have a document selected

Comment: So I made a seperate html page for that image and got it working, however it still won't style.. I edited with the current code I have.

Comment: Andrew, thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Seperate html doc with the following is what did it for me.

<img src="coolcenturylink.jpg" width="100%" height="98%"/>